# mysql server changing data directory

Tags: server, mysql

I am new to ubuntu and I was trying to learn mysql. I made mysql server and started working with it. But then I wanted to change the data directory so I followed these steps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory

But I think I messed everything up. Can somebody please help me, this is the error I am getting while restarting mysql server

```
root@vijay-desktop:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d# sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

[....] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

`

Comment: Run `journalctl -xe` and update Your question with output of this command.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for the reply but I solved it. Actually I have mentioned incorrect path. Now it is working